# How to fix Ambiguous handler methods mapped for REST API

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

New Rest API was developed with few resource GET endpoints. When calling the endpoints i get below error:
Ambiguous handler methods mapped

I get 500 error. where am i going wrong. Please assist. Thanks

I tried setting requestmapping to name, path no difference.

controller class:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
Page<AuditEntity> AuditPageable(Pageable pageable) {

    return auditRepository.findAll(pageable);
}


@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@GetMapping("/{messageId}")
public Optional<AuditEntity> messageById(@PathVariable("messageId") String messageId) {

    return auditRepository.findById(messageId);
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{serviceName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
List<AuditEntity> servicePageable(@RequestParam("serviceName") String serviceName) {
    List<AuditEntity> services = auditRepository.findAll().stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return services;
}
```

Interface code:

public interface AuditRepository extends JpaRepository {
    Page findByMessageContains(@Param("message") String message, Pageable pageable);

I expect GET calls return data and not throw any 500 errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest API path is the same for the below API's

```
1. @GetMapping("/{messageId}")

2. @RequestMapping(value = "/{serviceName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Hence you are getting Ambiguous handler methods mapped

Answer (score 2):

Consider, for instance, the following HTTP request:

```
GET /list/foo HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

Spring cannot distinguish whether it will be handled by the first or by the second method:

```java
@GetMapping("/{messageId}")
Optional<AuditEntity> messageById(@PathVariable("messageId") String messageId) {
   ...
}
```

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/{serviceName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
List<AuditEntity> servicePageable(@RequestParam("serviceName") String serviceName) {
    ...
}
```

Both request mappings are ambiguous for Spring and suitable for handling the request.

---

To fix it, you probably want to replace the second method shown above with:

```java
@GetMapping
List<AuditEntity> servicePageable(@RequestParam("serviceName") String serviceName) {
    ...
}
```

So the HTTP request can be like:

```
GET /list?serviceName=foo HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

Where `foo` is the value of the `serviceName` parameter.

For the first method, a request will be like:

```
GET /list/foo HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

Where `foo` is the value of the `messageId` parameter.